# How to handle POST request data from axios to Laravel API (Process it/Manipulate it)

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, request, axios

I doing a simple project to order pizzas. I've made a laravel api of it and then a frontend to connect to the laravel api. I been using Axios in my post to the laravel api but how to use the request data to be save to the database, I'm having trouble with it for a long time.

Here is my codes so far

Api.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

let BaseApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api"
  // baseURL: "http://pizzaorderapp.test/api"
});

let Api = function() {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (token) {
    BaseApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return BaseApi;
};

export default Api;
```

Pizzas.js (The method that I defined to access POST /api/pizza

```
addPizza(pizza) {
return Api().post("/pizza", {
  data: qs.stringify(pizza),
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Pizzas.vue (Method in Vue Template)

```
addPizza() {
  this.pizza.user_id = this.user.id;
  console.log(this.pizza.user_id);
  console.log(this.pizza);
  if (this.edit === false) {
    // Add Pizza
    Pizzas.addPizza(this.pizza)
      .then(() => {
        this.$root.$emit("addPizza", true);
        this.pizza.customer_name = "";
        this.pizza.type = "";
        this.crust = "";
        alert("Pizza Order Added!");
        this.fetchPizzas();
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Here is my laravel api store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Get the authenticated user to add order
    $user = $request->user();

    $pizza = $request->isMethod('put') ? Pizza::findOrFail($request->pizza_id) : new Pizza;

    $pizza->id = $request->input('pizza_id');
    $pizza->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $pizza->customer_name = $request->input('customer_name');
    $pizza->type = $request->input('type'); 
    $pizza->crust = $request->input('crust');

    if($pizza->save()) {
        return new PizzaResource($pizza);
    }
    

}
```

After I submit the information in the UI, It returned 500 server error.
Can you help me please.

Comment: Take a look at your laravel log file to get detailed information on what went wrong

Comment: I've tried to get the $request->all(), I didn't get anything.